# Developer branch in source tree

Tags: github

In source tree I do not have a developer branch and cannot download the files, can anyone help with this? The other members of my group all have access.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you get any error messages? You need to provide a [mcve] to allow us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go the sidebar in SourceTree, look out for "Remotes".
2. If it is collapsed, click on show.
3. Then go to "origin" (this refers to the files on Github) and right click (or context-click) on the "develop" branch. Select "checkout". This "selects" the develop branch. But we still have to get it to your local machine. This will be done in 4.
4. In the prompt, you have to give the new branch (develop) a name. But for now, just leave it as it is and click "ok".
5. Now, you have a local develop branch that "tracks" the origin develop brunch. `Commit` changes to your local branch and then `push` them to the origin.

To learn some more about git, I suggest you this short course: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1